# Null pointer exception DrawerLayout

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, drawerlayout

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView mNavigationDrawer;


private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
 DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "pref";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_DrawerLayout);

    mNavigationDrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawer.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_list)));

    setDrawers(mDrawerLayout, mToolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void setDrawers(DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mToolbar = toolbar;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer)
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
            saveToPreference(getApplicationContext(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer + "");
//                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
//                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState)
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mNavigationDrawer);

    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
}

public static void saveToPreference(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
//        editor.commit()
}

public static String readFromPreference(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
}
}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:name="@+id/main_DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="xymen.chetanbhagatnovels.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@null"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It is giving me error on line mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
I dont know why. I also have another project from which I have copied all but it is nor getting error but this one does. HELP

Comment: Do you have more than one activity_main.xml file?  E.g., one in layout and another in layout_land?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code and figured it out.

The problem is that you have specified `name` instead of `id` for the `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`.

Just change this:

```
android:name="@+id/main_DrawerLayout"
```

To this:

```
android:id="@+id/main_DrawerLayout"
```

With that change, the NullPointerException was fixed and it ran fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited information you've provided, your mDrawerLayout member is null.

This can happen if you have multiple versions of the same layout file in different layout folders that are inconsistent with one another.

I suspect you have a layout file named main_activity.xml in your res/layout folder that has declared a DrawerLayout view with the id main_DrawerLayout, and another version of this layout file (perhaps in your res/layout-land folder) that either does not have this DrawerLayout view, or has it but declared with a different view id.

As a result findViewById(R.id.main_DrawerLayout) is returning null from one of your alternate main_activity.xml layouts and you are getting a NullPointerException as a result.